# How many thread pools can exist on a single machine?

Tags: c#, threadpool

Theoretically, it appears that there can be multiple thread-pools on a single machine but .Net framework only has a single thread pool per machine even when the machine has multiple processors. **Is this statement true?**

**UPDATE 1:**

From Tim's comment, the answer is that there will be one .Net threadpool per process. So if multiple processes are running on a single machine then multiple .Net threadpools can exist on that machine.

Comment: What's your source for that statement?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, That is just my best guess based on what I know, but not sure if its accurate.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, You think my question is not valid?

Comment: @TimMedora, Can you post your comment so I can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **There is one thread pool per process.** Beginning with the .NET
>   Framework 4, the default size of the thread pool for a process depends
>   on several factors, such as the size of the virtual address space. A
>   process can call the GetMaxThreads method to determine the number of
>   threads. The number of threads in the thread pool can be changed by
>   using the SetMaxThreads method.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx) (empthasis mine)

A thread pool provides a configuration "container", for example, you might want to control the number of threads available to a particular application or service.

> ...even when the machine has multiple processors

The number of cores does impact thread pool defaults, but it doesn't limit the number of thread pools that can be created.